# Error 'The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request message multiple times'

Tags: c#

This is what I am trying:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> post(string specificUrl, string token, StringContent inputData) // specificUrl like "user/" at the end "/"
{
    var policy = Policy
        .Handle<Exception>()
        .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(res => !res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        .RetryAsync(3);

    string fullUrl = baseUrl + specificUrl;
    using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, fullUrl))
    {
        requestMessage.Content = inputData;
        requestMessage.Headers.Add("access_token", token);
        //HttpResponseMessage res = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage).ConfigureAwait(false);
        HttpResponseMessage res = await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => client.SendAsync(requestMessage)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return res;
    }
}
```

As soon as the code hits the waitAndRetryPolicy and awaits the required amount of time, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The request message was already sent. Cannot send the same request message multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, you cannot reuse a `HttpRequestMessage`. It takes care of a whole bunch of concerns (such as streamed content, etc.) that cannot be mitigated at the `SendAsync` level.

You will need to create or recreate your `HttpRequestMessage` in the `ExecuteAsync` lambda, or even better, use `IHttpClientFactory` and then use *[Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly)* at the `HttpClientBuilder` level instead.

Example of recreating the `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
return await policy.ExecuteAsync(() =>
{
   // Note the 'using' here is a superfluous, but good practice
   using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, fullUrl)
   {
       Content = new StringContent(aString)
   };

   requestMessage.Headers.Add("access_token", token);
   return client.SendAsync(requestMessage);

}).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

However, ideally you should be using `HttpClientFactory` with a typed or named client.

**Given a typed client**

```
public class MyTypedClient
{
   private readonly HttpClient _client;

   public MyTypedClient(HttpClient client) => _client = client;
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MyCall(string inputData)
   {
      using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/someRoute") { Content = new StringContent(inputData) };
      var result = await _client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
      result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
      return result;
   }
}
```

**Example [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) Usage**

```
private static readonly AsyncRetryPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> retryPolicy
   = HttpPolicyExtensions
      .HandleTransientHttpError() // Whatever??
      .RetryAsync(3);

public static void Main()
{
   var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

   serviceCollection
      .AddHttpClient<MyTypedClient>(ClientConfiguration)
      .AddPolicyHandler(retryPolicy);

   var provider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
   // Whatever
}

private static void ClientConfiguration(HttpClient client)
{
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://bob.com");
   /// blah blah blah
}
```

<sub>***Note**: This is not meant to be a tutorial on dependency injection (DI), Polly, or anything else such as the world's best practice, how to use authentication at the `AddHttpClient` level, etc. It's just an example use case of how this might fit together using policies*</sub>

**Nuggets**

- Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- Microsoft.Extensions.Http
- Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Polly
- Polly

---

**Additional Resources**

- [Use IHttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests)
- [Implement HTTP call retries with exponential backoff with IHttpClientFactory and Polly policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly)

Comment: thanks it is very informative, the first ```return await policy.ExecuteAsync(() =>{}``` trigger error of ': Cannot access a disposed object :'System.Net.Http.StringContent'.'.

Comment: @ShowMore ahh yes my mistake, best to create the content every time as well (in this case), there is more to this issue, however ill modify to give you an example

Comment: I still don't understand how a DelegatingHandler is allowed to resend the `HttpRequestMessage` without triggering the exception that the message has already been sent. Is it cloning the message somehow under the covers?